# Error In Crystal Syntax - Looking For Work Around

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report which each record should contain a STATUS. For those record without a STATUS I have created a simple `IF ISNULL` formula to highlight those.

```
IF ISNULL ( {PO._POstatus} )
THEN "Unknown Status"
ELSE {PO._POstatus}
```

Some records are returning blank status' still. These records a notice has a LEN of 0. Is there a way I could write this formula to look for both NULL AND LEN of 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
IF ISNULL ( {PO._POstatus} ) OR {PO._POstatus} = "" THEN "Unknown Status" ELSE {PO._POstatus}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I thought I had tried something along these lines to check for both NULL and "". No field should be = to "", but for whatever reasons Crystal reports they're not NULL.